# Most frequent value in dataset (with variation)

Tags: c++, math, statistics, average

This is a part programming, part statistical math question.
I have a dataset where I want to get the most frequent number (mode), the problem is that I am dealing with values with slight variation.

So normally {1,2,50,50,90} the most frequent number would be 50

But in my case the numbers look like this:
{1,2,49,50,51,90} but the result is still 50

So my question is how can I efficiently calculate this number and is there a statistical term for this number?

Some pseudo code:

```
Float items.val[] = {1,2,49,50,51,90};
Float threshold = 4;
For (item in items) {
    For (subitem in items){
           Float dist=Distance(time,subitem)
           If (dist < threshold){
                 item.dist += dist
           }
     }
}
Output=Sort(item.dist)[0]
```

Comment: How is this programming related? And why is the result 50?

Comment: I need to write a c++ function to calculate it. The number is 50 because I need the most frequent number, with slight variation. So while I can't find the most frequent number I can find the one with the most "nearby neighbors"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Read [ask].

Comment: @Amit added some pseudo code to show what I want to do.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Voting to close.

Comment: @duffymo I can see that the question is not strictly about programming, but it is far from nonsensical.

Comment: How do you _exactly_ define "with slight variation?"  This is the starting point.  Unless this is clear, one cannot tell if it is a statistical question, and there is no way to write code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to go about this.

(1) the most careful, exact way is to assume a probabilistic model for the observed values, and look for the mode (as the expected value or most probable or some other criterion) of the inferred values. I am going to guess this is far too much work in this case, although given unlimited time I would certainly want to approach it that way.

(2) construct a histogram, and look for the bin which has the greatest density (with density = (#items in bin)/(width of bin)). This doesn't necessarily yield a single value.

(3) fit a parametric distribution to the observed values, and report the mode of the fitted distribution.

You might get more traction for this question at stats.stackexchange.com. Good luck and have fun.

EDIT: After looking at your example code, I see it is not too different from (2) above. It seems like a reasonable and workable approach.